# How to derive the Black Scholes partial differential equation from a stock log-normal distribution?

Tags: black-scholes

Is there a way to go from this

$$\ln S_t=\ln S_0+(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t $$

$$\ln S_t\sim N[\ln S_0+(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t, (\sigma^2)t]$$

To the Black-Scholes partial differential equation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quant.SE! I tried to reformat your question but it is still unclear. I can only guess what you ask and the answer is: Try to take your process and see if its an Ito process and what the ito formula looks like. I wouldnt be surprised if you end up with the black scholes SPDE. (please take a look at your question as well. something is still not right there!!)

Comment: Your equation looks quite off. For $t = 0$ it implies that $S_0 \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \ln S_0, 0 \right)$. Also - your question is not clear to me. Is $S_t$ supposed to follow a geometric Brownian motion? If yes, what do you want to know that goes beyond the standard derivation of the PDE that you find in most textbooks?

Comment: Im writing on my ipad and its hard to write the equations correctly

Comment: Your equations are looking OK now (I rolled back one of your edits that didn't make sense). My previous question still stands: what do you want to know that goes beyond the standard derivation of the PDE that you find in most textbooks?

Comment: I want to go from this to the BS partial differential equation but no book ive found goes this route. Should i apply itos lemma on ln St?

Comment: You use Ito to get $\mathrm{d}S_t$. Then you follow the usual approach of setting up a self-financing and locally risk-free portfolio consisting of the contingent claim and the underlying asset. I like the exposition in Musiela and Rutkowski's "Martingale Methods in Financial Modelling" (Chapter 3.1).

Comment: Can you use ito on d ln st?

Comment: Given the dynamics for $\ln \left( S_t \right)$, you can apply Ito to find the dynamics for $S_t$. This (or the other way around) is usually one of the first examples you find in any textbook. As your questions are very basic, I am voting to close this as off topic and recommend you to look into some introductory textbooks. In addition to the reference I provided before, I recommend Shreve's "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II".

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote in your question is simply one of the assumptions of the Black-Scholes framework.

The whole interesting part about getting to the Black-Scholes PDE (i.e. constructing a replicating portfolio) comes next and is the most common derivation of the Black-Scholes formula, which you can find the derivation on the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation).